# TYPO3 extbase extend news controller

Tags: typo3, extbase, tx-news

TYPO3 6.1

I wanted to call some function on opening of extbase news list view.

For example, if the url to list view contains `tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][tags]=1`, then I want to update that "tags" count by 1 in database.

How this could be possible ? Any help ?

Answer (score 4):

And if You will just extend the class You need ?

```
config.tx_extbase {
    objects {
        Tx_FooExt_Controller_OriginalController.className = Tx_MyExt_Controller_OtherController
    }
}
```

It looks like easiest way.

#### References

- http://blog.sebastiaandejonge.com/articles/2013/june/11/class-extension-in-extbase/
- http://lists.typo3.org/pipermail/typo3-english/2011-December/078458.html

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to just add a simple user function by TS and do it there